# Props is not showing something on the screen

Tags: reactjs, react-props

I am trying to show the number 0 on the screen using props. However nothing shows on the screen and I am not sure why. This is the code:

```
import React,{Component} from 'react';
import Toolbar from './Toolbar.js';

    class Counter extends Component {
        constructor(props) {
        super(props);
     this.state ={
                counter:0   
             
     }
};
render() {
    return(
        <div>
              {this.state.counter.map(count=>(
                   <Toolbar count={count}/>
                ))}
            </div>
    )
}
};

export default Counter;
```

And this is where I called it

```
<div className="toolbar__cart">
                    <span>{props.count}</span>
                        <a href="/Cart"><img src="Images/basket.png" alt="Basket" width="40"/></a></div>
```

Comment: `this.state.counter` is a [Number](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number). You are calling the `.map` method on a number, which doesn't seem correct. Try simply rendering `<Toolbar count={this.state.counter}/>`

Comment: still not working

Comment: can you provide any error messages from the console?

Comment: Failed prop type: Invalid prop 'component' supplied to 'Route': the prop is not a valid React component

Comment: There's no `<Route />` component in your sample. Can you please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with your code?

Comment: I am not sure what other code i can send to you. that's all the code

Comment: Hmm, can you copy and paste the entire console output? Including any tracebacks? The error message you have shown doesn't seem to match up with any of the code you have provided

Comment: The console it's too long and it doesn't let me send it to you

Comment: is it any way i can send a picture?

Comment: images are discouraged since we cannot copy and paste text from an image

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the `map` function is applicable here since the value of `counter` is an integer and not an array. See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) for more info on the `map` function.

If you just want your `Toolbar` component to display the value of `this.state.counter`, you could use this:

```js
return(
  <Toolbar count={this.state.counter}></Toolbar>
)
```

And then your `Toolbar` component would use that `counter` value like this:

```js
function Toolbar(props) {
  return (
    <div>
      <span>{props.count}</span>
      <a href="/Cart"><img src="Images/basket.png" alt="Basket" width="40"/></a>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `map` function incorrectly.

`.map` is a function used along with an array

Check out : https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_map.asp

Correct Code :

```
render() {
return (
  <div>
    <Toolbar count={this.state.counter} />
  </div>
);
```

}

You can checkout full code here : https://codesandbox.io/s/naughty-lederberg-hb4wp?file=/src/App.js:203-309

Comment: Did u check the link I shared? It shows 0 beside basket image.
Link - https://hb4wp.csb.app/

Comment: Yes i have. I am not sure why on mine it's not working

Answer (score 0):

`counter.map` map function for Arrays - sample

```
import React,{Component} from 'react';
import Toolbar from './Toolbar.js';

    class Counter extends Component {
        constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state ={
                counter:[0,1,2]  
        }
};
render() {
    return(
        <div>
              {this.state.counter.map(count=>(
                   <Toolbar count={count}/>
                ))}
            </div>
    )
}
};
```